# svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed while testing connection on VCS tab of Teamcity

Tags: svn, teamcity

I am using Teamcity 8.0 trial version and on the vcs settings tab I entered the url inside the svn settings the one that i used in svn repo browser but while testing connection i am getting the error as mentioned. What is that I am doing wrong. 
OS : win 8
teamcity version 8.0
svn : 1.7

Answer (score 0):

That must be something simply as you may have written the url wrong,

or you´re missing the username and/or password to log in?

or you don´t have enought permission.

You must specify better that question i guess.

Comment: user name and pwd is same as the one i use with svn , url is copied from svn repo browser and with my username and pwd it is taking me to the specified folder in svn

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by just uninstalling kaspersky from my machine. strange but truth.